# How to get this div above the another div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I can't get this div above another div that I have in Bootstrap. Basically I have two divs within another div. One of the div's has an image in it and the other has text.

I've tried many things like changing the margin using CSS but it doesn't work for some reason.

```
<div id="header" class="position-relative overflow-hidden p-3 p-md-5 m-md-3 text-center bg-dark">
        <div>
            <img id="andro" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div id="mainP" class="bg-dark mx-auto mx-auto center-block">
          Text in here
        </div>
    </div>


#andro{
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
    opacity: .5;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}

#mainP{
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    margin-right: 50vw;
}
```

So I want the div "mainP" to be above the div "andro" but I don't know why it won't when I try to change the margin and the z-index using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In your description, you have given id to img, not to div.

PS. Your code is not complete. Please add both css and Html or a working sample via codepen /Fiddle. We won't be able to help without seeing what exactly is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the two inner divs in a div with `.row` as a class you can then use the reording classes built into bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering

```
  <div id="header" class="row position-relative overflow-hidden p-3 p-md-5 m-md-3 text-center bg-dark">
            <div class="order-2">
                <img id="andro" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div id="mainP" class="order-1 bg-dark mx-auto mx-auto center-block">
              Text in here
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you.

Please wrap image and text container (#mainP) in one div.

Please try below CSS.

```css
    #mainP{
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> 

<div class="position-relative d-inline-block">
            <img id="andro" src="https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/orange_crush_514795.jpg" class="img-fluid">
             <div id="mainP" class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          Text in here
        </div>
        </div>
```